# Sufficient condition for number of lattice points to be close to the volume

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I'm looking for a theorem of the following form. Let $r$ be an open region in $\mathop{R}^{3}$ with a well-defined, finite surface area. Let $v$ be the volume of $r$; let $a$ be the surface area of $r$; and let $n$ be the number of integer lattice points contained in $r$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $b$, such that, if $v/a > b$ then $1- \epsilon < |n - v|/v < 1+\epsilon$. The intuition is that the difference between the volume and the number of interior integer points depends on edge effects whose size is limited by the surface area.

Comment: If you take any region and remove tiny balls around lattice points, you will change neither volume nor surface area much. But the number of lattice points can change significantly.

Comment: Things like this are in Minkowski's "Geometry of numbers"... as keyword/phrase.

Comment: What you will require is that your region is defined in some reasonable way. Usually the needed requirement is for your region to be defined by some $o$-minimal structure. For example, if your region is semi-algebraic then you have Davenport's lemma telling you that the number of lattice points is well approximated by the volume, provided that the projection onto all coordinate planes and coordinate axes are suitably small. In particular, it is not enough to assume that the surface area is small; you also have to avoid long rods.